# Finding hourly averages of CSV file using python

Tags: python, csv, numpy

So I have a code where I am inputting a CSV file that has two columns. The first is the date and time which is by minutes and its about a month and a half long (4/20/2016  2:39:00 PM - 5/29/2016  11:59:00 PM) and the second is my data, each point ranges from 0-360. I have 36,044 points of data. So I am trying to organize it by finding the hourly averages. I thought first by organizing it by datetime and then using pandas to organize it but I can't get it to work. I am relatively new to using python.

```
import csv
import numpy as np

#opening csv file
f = open('Rmyoung_date_wind_dir.csv')

#reading in all the data from the file row by row
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    date=np.datetime64(row[0])

    direction=row[1]

#adding 15 degrees to all directions 
    dircor=direction + 15


#making sure that no numbers exceed 360    
    if dircor > 360:
        dircor = dircor - 360

#now finding hourly averages
```

Comment: I'm guessing that one hour does not nicely map to a particular number of rows? That each point of data could be an irregular time step from the previous?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas is exactly what you want

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Rmyoung_date_wind_dir.csv', index_col=0, squeeze=True, parse_dates=True, header=None)
data.resample('H', how='mean')
```

Comment: `parse_date=True` applies to the index. `[0]` would work too.

Comment: Thank you. I tried printing (data) and it still gave me the data by minutes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "data by minutes"?